# Python 3 with Jupyter notebook: Cannot import file in the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python 3 on Windows 10 within a Jupyter notebook. I have two files in the same directory, Test1.py and Test2.py

In Test1 I have:

```
def method1():
print ("Hello World!")
```

And in Test2 I have:

```
from Test1 import method1
```

But when running Test2 I get the error:

```
No module named 'Test1'
```

I know this question has been asked before, so I tried the main suggestion: add the current directory to sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/Test1')
```

However, this solution does not work for me and I still get the same error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I gave up. But I'm using Spyder and it works there

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put a  __init__.py in your directory which have Test1.py and Test2.py.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I still get the same error.